# I used fetch() method to load data from external server. All data are being loaded properly. But I came across dificulity when I use querySelector

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load data from an external server and render it on my web page by using javascript. I used `fetch(url)` to load the data. Data is being loaded properly; I can see all of it in the console. What happens is that, when I use `document.querySelector()`, only 1 article is shown on my web page despite there being 10 articles. Then, I used `document.querySelectorAll()`, but nothing showed on my web page and there were no errors, no information in the console as well. What I did was this:

```js
let url = "https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?lang=en&max=50&token=TOKEN_HERE";
    
fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(details) {
        let allArticles = details.articles;
        allArticles.forEach(function(article) {
            let header = document.querySelector('.heading');
            header.innerText = article.title;

            let description = document.querySelector('.description');
            description.innerText = article.description;

            let content = document.querySelector('.content');
            content.innerText = article.content;
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <h4 class="heading"></h4>
    <p class="description"></p>
    <p class="content"></p>
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Comment: you override it each time thats why, so only the last article will be shown, you need to append new elements not replace existing elements using innerText. You should create new elements using document.createElement()

Answer (score 1):

You will need to generate DOM. Use your HTML structure as template for each article.

```js
const buildArticle = (id, title, desc, content) => {
  return `
    <div id="article-${id}"">
    <h4 class="heading">${title}</h4>
    <p class="description">${desc}</p>
    <p class="content">${content}</p>
 </div>
`;
};

let url =
  "https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?lang=en&max=50&token=368273b6710cecf2476380400a7635c2";

fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (details) {
    let allArticles = details.articles;

    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = allArticles
      .map(function (article, idx) {
        return buildArticle(
          idx,
          article.title,
          article.description,
          article.content
        );
      })
      .join("");
  });
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

alternate way

```js
const createArticle = (id, title, desc, content) => {
  const article = document
    .querySelector("#article-template")
    .content.cloneNode(true);
  article.querySelector(".article").id = `article-${id}`;
  article.querySelector(".heading").textContent = title;
  article.querySelector(".description").textContent = desc;
  article.querySelector(".content").textContent = content;
  return article;
};

const url =
  "https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?lang=en&max=50&token=368273b6710cecf2476380400a7635c2";

fetch(url)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((details) =>
    details.articles.forEach((article, idx) =>
      document
        .getElementById("app")
        .appendChild(
          createArticle(
            idx,
            article.title,
            article.description,
            article.content
          )
        )
    )
  );
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<template id="article-template">
  <div class="article">
    <h4 class="heading"></h4>
    <p class="description"></p>
    <p class="content"></p>
  </div>
</template>;
```

Comment: Quick, dirty, and working! 